# How to select from a table and classify values in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

T1:

```
ID      Tag                     Name 
001     [country].[Province]    Ontario
002     [Country].[City]        Toronto
```

I want to select values from T1 and insert to another table(T2) and add some values based on province/city;
Sample T2:

```
Col1       Col2      
Ontario    Province 
Toronto    City
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Is the format of the `TAG` column always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `regexp_substr` to retrieve part of the `TAG` column:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id VARCHAR2(3),
  tag VARCHAR2(40),
  name VARCHAR2(40)
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('001', '[country].[Province]', 'Ontario');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('002', '[country].[City]', 'Toronto');

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  col1 VARCHAR2(40),
  col2 VARCHAR2(40)
);
```

If you are using Oracle 10g:

```
INSERT INTO t2
  SELECT name,
         rtrim(
           ltrim(
             regexp_substr(tag, '[[][a-zA-Z]*[]]', 1, 2),
             '['),
           ']') FROM t1;
```

If you are using Oracle 11g:

```
INSERT INTO t2
  SELECT name, regexp_substr(tag, '[[]([a-zA-Z]*)[]]', 1, 2, NULL, 1) FROM t1;
```

Test:

```
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Output:

```
COL1                COL2                 
------------------- ----------------------
Ontario             Province               
Toronto             City
```